# How to conditionally update sub-attribute in an UPSERT statement?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to update attribute `regions` by the following conditions:

- If region R does not exist in `regions` then push new region R to `regions`
- Else if region R exists then update attribute `accounts` for that region R in `regions`

So that no duplicate region for the same edge and no duplicate account for the same region.

This is my AQL:

```
1     FOR t IN transactions
2       SORT t.accountId, t.recordedAt
3       COLLECT accountIds = t.accountId INTO g
4       FOR i IN 0..LENGTH(g)-2
5         LET region = g[i].t.region
6         LET doc = (i == 0)
7           ? [{"_from": "status/root", "_to": CONCAT("status/", g[0].t.status), "recordedAt": g[i].t.recordedAt, "region": region, "level": i, "accountId": accountIds}
8             ,{"_from": CONCAT("status/", g[i].t.status), "_to": LENGTH(g) > 1 ? CONCAT("status/", g[i+1].t.status) : null, "recordedAt": g[i+1].t.recordedAt, "region": region, "level": i + 1, "accountId": accountIds}]
9           : [{"_from": CONCAT("status/", g[i].t.status), "_to": LENGTH(g) > 1 ? CONCAT("status/", g[i+1].t.status) : null, "recordedAt": g[i+1].t.recordedAt, "region": region, "level": i + 1, "accountId": accountIds}]
10      FOR d IN doc
11        FILTER d._to != null
12        UPSERT {"_from": d._from, "_to": d._to, "level": d.level}
13        INSERT {"_from": d._from, "_to": d._to, "level": d.level, "regions": [{"name": d.region, "accounts": [{"id": d.accountId, "recordedAt": d.recordedAt}]}]}
14        UPDATE {
15          "regions": 
16             OLD.regions[*].name ANY == d.region
17             ? PUSH(OLD.regions, {"name": d.region, "accounts": PUSH(OLD.regions[* FILTER CURRENT.name == d.region].accounts[**], {"id": d.accountId, "recordedAt": d.recordedAt})}, true)
18             : PUSH(OLD.regions, {"name": d.region, "accounts": [{"id": d.accountId, "recordedAt": d.recordedAt}]})
19        }
20        IN patterns
```

Actual Result:

```
{
    "_from": "status/root",
    "_to": "status/A",
    "level": 0,
    "regions": [
      {
        "name": "North",
        "accounts": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "recordedAt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "South",
        "accounts": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "recordedAt": "2012-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "North",
        "accounts": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "recordedAt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "recordedAt": "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "_from": "status/root",
    "_to": "status/A",
    "level": 0,
    "regions": [
      {
        "name": "North",
        "accounts": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "recordedAt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "recordedAt": "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "South",
        "accounts": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "recordedAt": "2012-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Sample data: [transaction.jsonl](https://pastebin.com/ZswbyVHM)

Thank you

Comment: I tried to find a solution for this, but I have a hard time to understand the grouping criteria to be honest. So the `regions` array should only contain every region name once, but the `accounts` array should not contain duplicate `id`s either? If there are multiple transactions, all with the same `id` and `region`, should they be ignored except for one? Only if they have the same `status` and/or `recordedAt` timestamp? Can you provide the full expected result (all edges)? It would also help if you could explain what you try to ultimate solve.

Comment: I have changed my design a bit  by removing `regions` and promote `accounts`. By keeping `region` I can count how many accounts in that region. For more details about the purpose of this graph, please go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214182/can-graph-db-solve-my-graph-problems