# Can graph db solve my graph problems?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

I have transactions data (pastebin.com/ZswbyVHM) like this:

```
{"accountId":3,"recordedAt":"2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z","region":"South","status":"H"}
{"accountId":3,"recordedAt":"2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","region":"South","status":"A"}
{"accountId":3,"recordedAt":"2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z","region":"South","status":"B"}
{"accountId":3,"recordedAt":"2014-03-01T00:00:00.000Z","region":"South","status":"E"}
{"accountId":3,"recordedAt":"2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z","region":"South","status":"C"}
```

when group transactions by `accountId` it can be viewed as:

```
{"accountId": 3, "region":"South", "transactions": [
    {"recordedAt":"2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "status": "H"},
    {"recordedAt":"2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "status": "A"},
    {"recordedAt":"2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z", "status": "B"}]
}
```

From above view I would like to create a graph of status relation from transactions collection 
that can preserve the order of status, `recordedAt`, `accountId` with the following properties:

- Nodes of the graph represent the status and implicitly the order of status.
- Their edges have `accounts`, an array of accountId having the same status changing from one to another at the same order.
- The path of the graph is intersection between `accountId`, `status` and `level` (the order of status).

[Example: Status Relation Graph](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&target=blank&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7Vtbd6M2EP41fiRHIK6PtpPdfdj29Jz0nHYfMciYFiMX48Tpr68EEkYgbDlcGm%2BcF%2BOxNBpp9H0zI5EZXG6PXzN%2Ft%2FkFhyiZGSA8zuDjzDB0YHjkg0reSonp2qUgyuKQNToJnuN%2FEe%2FJpIc4RHuhYY5xksc7URjgNEVBLsj8LMOvYrM1TsRRd36EWoLnwE%2Fa0j%2FiMN%2BUUtewT%2FJvKI42fGTdZhNe%2BcHfUYYPKRtvZsB18Vf%2BvPW5LjbR%2FcYP8WtNBJ9mcJlhnJdP2%2BMSJXRt%2BbKV%2Fb50%2FFrZnaE0V%2BlglB1e%2FOSAuMV2Qrou1phoIAZy39j%2FHKhRC3h6JE8R%2FfSDgMw4J2s%2BJz1m1oLrIOOWasp2XBzGL03RFaPNnAW1fk7muiRdMhTFOC2Gtv3tjjRIV3v68SvOyGKzNgHOQhTOc2ZipdQAuq0BVwN6bSDnsXMCy9ovkmnURcxMo2UmeMYHJcsMDVhty643wWyboLo4jgbMlglWtT6rrDl806hik%2BdvHFgoJDhjX1Ocko9FgRZE9yMg3zb5NiGPOnlExzj%2Fk4np8w8uT%2FPsrfjhweJff7B2f6E8f2N84h9yTER0pjjCqZ98x3jHdFCvsma6XRlaxw2nHT%2BLEBMx9NM51NowYH1FeIuIJaQBo0ENPADXdstOjAg1piNDiZ%2FHLyLd%2BIy1okpVpf03HBcAYaqhawlqdc8QVezxIQsQ61XHf0ORbgNBkeE1bCnnr6BI7IbX6z0SepCH2iKdRAUhyckJdpLTfuenwsbi25P6VStZhO7lLQrjw%2FY6xip1j8FY8P1UADXKBp047CDaSeCpjwDPTjiW%2B5olFW2EetchFDw4lmkKADBhP4AOCgDzYnS%2BBABo747tDVnkF11bp7klkoRkXXQnvG7iHD3v%2FGL9X0niJ%2B4Hf78rU7F1fKT7ZVHlNuCcR19QlqOjiregA0XS40nUay1FY6JNLTvjMpn3BOec8YTV6Ykz1HDJOborc8612dTlNGDIHEs5cyBplScy1vlpCLTbzHNknDzmvBWStu6cze4zbYHTVaY9RIJVEvX%2FweF2m8N141oSB0aDxD3wgUjcHonE57fH4BVj82zTdSZjcGckqKjC4RyklKDitaGiXJEoA0F1Nd3em1o3hwh%2BfaKv1ACFXP1s2KPV8gSJOgFcLu7QDJGp%2BauiAd1TO8plhYfJIhIDyNomcUSm8hiQXYYyIqDAjQM%2FmbMftnEY0v6LxF%2BhZFEdZS1xgrNiXH6YJduyTgcbVKd0zLhZ%2FaSro242xESvH5sfBfzwPF%2FsPgjT8yHuqJCgYory9Y6Kq1Gh6WJEhmMAA4KPD4xhznEuoQDeUXADKDDNMVDQPzrIC4Fvt1cI2HqjEHCmO8rhQ99u0cwrZKEUUK2aBy8FdO79T3Y2duaM6NKtnqN83yg5JOp7QvQBwwOHZP%2F4AB6A07gaGyRAOGL1oOkNIhokQHBc34%2BK2kdFpjdhhOi%2BePz0fvAmvHTRZfdfzZVKwzl94YeSU%2BLv93EgLlDnElwMlLUJWpIJWj3PmI%2Bimjf5sqne4zfU6MBqKOq4x38PS3XfhfUL7t%2FRC32NTA0hl6MYTbNYPNdrISxB61wSwHKagtFAG8Rp9HuRj2mmNBYOACpDDFFWG1K2ZMcZQ0Cq%2F22E3HlgOMdJ0o9BXDmE40SYQdC%2Bv4Bjec4ZyXP6Z%2FScJQljo3nObUet2yo4edwVrmmhYhwdvuDsPki5F5zygrP9guunOHbkyBukrqxQ0DPjc0Um0gxRwTA3UT3PuAYglm7aUqMcp005xuCU05VMiy5ybLWs%2FD2OGqvk7yaqmyk1HTBdqXnmXeN%2Bfni6PT80D%2Be9Kf3Q%2F5VXeSA3VP3wM2W5zoRZ7plXZPt5Dn5Gz3mSM4HRPHf79YnkNVKeQExfn9zf%2BOyOJVMe4xv9T0x%2Bmtyq6YcRcyvy9fT%2Fq2VKfPonYfj0Hw%3D%3D)

1. There are two statuses from root "A" and "H".
2. At level 0,

   AccountId 1, 2, 4 have the same status "A", except AccountId 3.

   The path of AccountId 4 ends at this level.
3. At level 1,

   AccountId 1, 2    have the same status "A",

   AccountId 3 have the same status "A" but from different path.

   The path of AccountId 1 ends at this level.
4. At level 2,

   AccountId 2 have the status "B".

   AccountId 3 have the same status "B" but from different path.
5. At level 3,

   AccountId 2 have the status "A" and AccountId 3 have the status "E"

So I designed 3 edge collections:

**Design 1:** Each edge is a relation between status vertex that uses `level` to keep the order of transaction.

```
{"_from": "status/root", "_to": "status/A", "level": 0, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-05-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/A"   , "_to": "status/A", "level": 1, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-06-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/A"   , "_to": "status/B", "level": 2, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-07-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/B"   , "_to": "status/A", "level": 3, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-08-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/A"   , "_to": "status/G", "level": 4, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-09-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/G"   , "_to": "status/G", "level": 5, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-10-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/G"   , "_to": "status/H", "level": 6, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-11-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/H"   , "_to": "status/D", "level": 7, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-12-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/D"   , "_to": "status/A", "level": 8, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2013-01-01"}]}
{"_from": "status/A"   , "_to": "status/A", "level": 9, "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2013-02-01"}]}
```

**Design 2:** Each edge is a relation between level vertex that has an edge attribute `status`.

```
{"_from": "level/root", "_to": "level/0", "status": "A", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-05-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/0"   , "_to": "level/1", "status": "A", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-06-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/1"   , "_to": "level/2", "status": "B", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-07-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/2"   , "_to": "level/3", "status": "A", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-08-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/3"   , "_to": "level/4", "status": "G", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-09-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/4"   , "_to": "level/5", "status": "G", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-10-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/5"   , "_to": "level/6", "status": "H", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-11-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/6"   , "_to": "level/7", "status": "D", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2012-12-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/7"   , "_to": "level/8", "status": "A", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2013-01-01"}]}
{"_from": "level/8"   , "_to": "level/9", "status": "A", "accounts": [{"id": 2, "region": "South", "recordedAt": "2013-02-01"}]}
```

**Design 3:** By adding virtual vertex (region, year).

This design try to eliminate `accounts` to avoid filtering array of objects. It is easier to filter by edge attribute.

```
{"_from": "level/root" , "_to": "level/South"}
{"_from": "level/South", "_to": "level/2012"}
{"_from": "level/2016" , "_to": "level/0", "status": "A", "accountId": 1}
{"_from": "level/2012" , "_to": "level/0", "status": "A", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/2017" , "_to": "level/0", "status": "A", "accountId": 4}
{"_from": "level/0"    , "_to": "level/1", "status": "A", "accountId": 1}
{"_from": "level/0"    , "_to": "level/1", "status": "A", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/1"    , "_to": "level/2", "status": "B", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/2"    , "_to": "level/3", "status": "A", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/3"    , "_to": "level/4", "status": "G", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/4"    , "_to": "level/5", "status": "G", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/5"    , "_to": "level/6", "status": "H", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/6"    , "_to": "level/7", "status": "D", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/7"    , "_to": "level/8", "status": "A", "accountId": 2}
{"_from": "level/8"    , "_to": "level/9", "status": "A", "accountId": 2}
```

- This [graph](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&target=blank&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7Vtbd6M2EP41fiRHIK6PtpPdfdj29Jz0nHYfMciYFiMX48Tpr68EEkYgbDlcGm%2BcF%2BOxNBpp9H0zI5EZXG6PXzN%2Ft%2FkFhyiZGSA8zuDjzDB0YHjkg0reSonp2qUgyuKQNToJnuN%2FEe%2FJpIc4RHuhYY5xksc7URjgNEVBLsj8LMOvYrM1TsRRd36EWoLnwE%2Fa0j%2FiMN%2BUUtewT%2FJvKI42fGTdZhNe%2BcHfUYYPKRtvZsB18Vf%2BvPW5LjbR%2FcYP8WtNBJ9mcJlhnJdP2%2BMSJXRt%2BbKV%2Fb50%2FFrZnaE0V%2BlglB1e%2FOSAuMV2Qrou1phoIAZy39j%2FHKhRC3h6JE8R%2FfSDgMw4J2s%2BJz1m1oLrIOOWasp2XBzGL03RFaPNnAW1fk7muiRdMhTFOC2Gtv3tjjRIV3v68SvOyGKzNgHOQhTOc2ZipdQAuq0BVwN6bSDnsXMCy9ovkmnURcxMo2UmeMYHJcsMDVhty643wWyboLo4jgbMlglWtT6rrDl806hik%2BdvHFgoJDhjX1Ocko9FgRZE9yMg3zb5NiGPOnlExzj%2Fk4np8w8uT%2FPsrfjhweJff7B2f6E8f2N84h9yTER0pjjCqZ98x3jHdFCvsma6XRlaxw2nHT%2BLEBMx9NM51NowYH1FeIuIJaQBo0ENPADXdstOjAg1piNDiZ%2FHLyLd%2BIy1okpVpf03HBcAYaqhawlqdc8QVezxIQsQ61XHf0ORbgNBkeE1bCnnr6BI7IbX6z0SepCH2iKdRAUhyckJdpLTfuenwsbi25P6VStZhO7lLQrjw%2FY6xip1j8FY8P1UADXKBp047CDaSeCpjwDPTjiW%2B5olFW2EetchFDw4lmkKADBhP4AOCgDzYnS%2BBABo747tDVnkF11bp7klkoRkXXQnvG7iHD3v%2FGL9X0niJ%2B4Hf78rU7F1fKT7ZVHlNuCcR19QlqOjiregA0XS40nUay1FY6JNLTvjMpn3BOec8YTV6Ykz1HDJOborc8612dTlNGDIHEs5cyBplScy1vlpCLTbzHNknDzmvBWStu6cze4zbYHTVaY9RIJVEvX%2FweF2m8N141oSB0aDxD3wgUjcHonE57fH4BVj82zTdSZjcGckqKjC4RyklKDitaGiXJEoA0F1Nd3em1o3hwh%2BfaKv1ACFXP1s2KPV8gSJOgFcLu7QDJGp%2BauiAd1TO8plhYfJIhIDyNomcUSm8hiQXYYyIqDAjQM%2FmbMftnEY0v6LxF%2BhZFEdZS1xgrNiXH6YJduyTgcbVKd0zLhZ%2FaSro242xESvH5sfBfzwPF%2FsPgjT8yHuqJCgYory9Y6Kq1Gh6WJEhmMAA4KPD4xhznEuoQDeUXADKDDNMVDQPzrIC4Fvt1cI2HqjEHCmO8rhQ99u0cwrZKEUUK2aBy8FdO79T3Y2duaM6NKtnqN83yg5JOp7QvQBwwOHZP%2F4AB6A07gaGyRAOGL1oOkNIhokQHBc34%2BK2kdFpjdhhOi%2BePz0fvAmvHTRZfdfzZVKwzl94YeSU%2BLv93EgLlDnElwMlLUJWpIJWj3PmI%2Bimjf5sqne4zfU6MBqKOq4x38PS3XfhfUL7t%2FRC32NTA0hl6MYTbNYPNdrISxB61wSwHKagtFAG8Rp9HuRj2mmNBYOACpDDFFWG1K2ZMcZQ0Cq%2F22E3HlgOMdJ0o9BXDmE40SYQdC%2Bv4Bjec4ZyXP6Z%2FScJQljo3nObUet2yo4edwVrmmhYhwdvuDsPki5F5zygrP9guunOHbkyBukrqxQ0DPjc0Um0gxRwTA3UT3PuAYglm7aUqMcp005xuCU05VMiy5ybLWs%2FD2OGqvk7yaqmyk1HTBdqXnmXeN%2Bfni6PT80D%2Be9Kf3Q%2F5VXeSA3VP3wM2W5zoRZ7plXZPt5Dn5Gz3mSM4HRPHf79YnkNVKeQExfn9zf%2BOyOJVMe4xv9T0x%2Bmtyq6YcRcyvy9fT%2Fq2VKfPonYfj0Hw%3D%3D) uses to query:

  1. Recall the status pattern for specific `accountId` by filtering path that all edges have specified id.

Pseudo AQL:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..20 OUTBOUND status/root statusRelations
  FILTER p.edges[*].accountId ALL == id
RETURN p.edges.status
```

2. Which statuses lead to interesting status (by region or year)?

Pseudo AQL:

```
FILTER e._to == "status/D" (AND e.region == "North" AND e.year == 2013)
RETURN SLICE(p.edges[*], -3) // RETURN 3 previous statuses that followed by "D"
```

3. Which is the most status that occurred by year?

Pseudo AQL:

```
FILTER e.year == 2013
COLLECT status = e.status WITH COUNT INTO length
RETURN status
```

Which one of my design is the best fit for ArangoDB and can answer my queries?